# HTTP Redirect Status code for redirect a web to the mobile version

Tags: http, mobile

Which HTTP redirect status code is the best for redirect a webpage to the mobile version?

From:
www.example.com

To:
m.example.com

Answer (score 6):

I would send a [301](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) while using [*Vary*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.44) to specify the request header fields that lead to this server-driven negotiation decision.

So, assuming that the *User-Agent* header field is used to distinguish whether the request was made by a mobile device, I would use this:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Vary: User-Agent
Location: http://m.example.com/...
```

Comment: The Google guidelines suggest that the "vary" header should be on the 200 response, rather than the 301 response.
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/redirects

Comment: @Spongeboy “If your site serves content or redirects users depending on the user-agent, i.e. the response varies, we strongly recommend that your server *also* send the Vary HTTP header on URLs that serve automatic redirects.” Note the emphasized “also”.

Comment: well spotted! Using 'vary' seems like the most graceful solution, but seens hard to implement in IIS URL Rewrite (which is what I'm using for redirects).

Comment: @Gumbo why a 301 in this case instead of a 302?  Both URLs are valid right?

Answer (score 4):

A temporary redirection (302 or 307) should be sufficient for this.

The [Google guidelines for smartphone site redirections](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/redirects) states-

> For this purpose, it does not matter if the server redirects with an
>   HTTP 301 or a 302 status code.

As such, a 302 is probably preferable over 307.

The guidelines suggest that the "vary" header should be part of the 200 response.

Comment: Im sure this probably just changed since you made this post but the quote you made from the google guidelines is followed by another sentence  that states 302 is preferable by google when possible.

"For this purpose, it does not matter if the server redirects with an HTTP 301 or a 302 status code, but use of 302 is recommended whenever possible."